# PHP Sorting files in a table

Tags: php, html-table, rows

Currently I have a table order by

```
A B C D

E F G H
```

but I would like to order the table by

```
A  E

B  F

C  G

D  H
```

Code:

```
for($i=0;$i<=count($aFiles);$i++)
{
   if($i%5==0)
   {
      echo "</tr><tr>";
   }

   echo '<td><a>'.$aFiles[$i].'</a></td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

Files are already sorted a-z in `$aFiles`.

Comment: HTML table is constructed row by row ( `<tr>` ). If you loop your result in order, it won't give you A > E > B > F ... Plus, you assumed the number of rows are fixed, as "E" is on 2nd column. You sure?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: the code example uses `count($aFiles)` to determine length, so the size is known before entering the loop.

Comment: but the code applies to first part only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$aFiles = array('a','b','c','d', 'e', 'f', 'g');



$iColumnNumber = 2;
$iRowMaxNumber = ceil(count($aFiles) / $iColumnNumber);

$iTableRow = 0;
$iTableColumns = 1;
$aTableRows = array();

// make array with table cells
foreach ($aFiles as $sFile)
{
    if ($iTableRow == $iRowMaxNumber)
    {
        $iTableRow = 0;
        $iTableColumns++;
    }

    if (!isset($aTableRows[$iTableRow]))
    {
        $aTableRows[$iTableRow] = array();
    }

    $aTableRows[$iTableRow][] = '<td>' . $sFile . '</td>';

    $iTableRow++;
}

// if there is odd number of elements
// we should add empty td elements
for ($iTableRow; $iTableRow < $iRowMaxNumber; $iTableRow++)
{
    if (count($aTableRows[$iTableRow]) < $iTableColumns)
    {
        $aTableRows[$iTableRow][] ='<td>empty</td>';
    }
}

// display table
echo '<table>';

foreach ($aTableRows as $aTableRow)
{

    echo '<tr>';
    echo implode('', $aTableRow);
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Thanks man, most of the answers worked for me, but with this one i have most control. T $aFiles is a list of folder files so the size is changed for every folder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the number of rows you want, you don't need to resort anything, just add some logic in your loop that generates the `<td>`s :

```
$size = count($aFiles);
echo '<table><tr>';
for($i=0;$i<=ceil($size/2);$i++) {
  if($i%2==0) {
    echo '<td><a>'.$aFiles[$i].'</a></td>';
    echo "</tr><tr>";
  } else {
    if(isset($aFiles[$i+floor($size/2)])) {
      echo '<td><a>'.$aFiles[$i+floor($size/2)].'</a></td>';
    }
  }
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: @ShivanRaptor:  was not including `<table>` `</table`, since it was only half included in the answer anyway. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Approach using HTML trick:

```
echo '<div class="tbl_group"><table>';
for($i=0;$i<=count($aFiles / 2);$i++)
{
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td><a>'.$aFiles[$i].'</a></td>';
   echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table></div>';
echo '<div class="tbl_group"><table>';
for($i=$aFiles / 2;$i<=count($aFiles);$i++)
{
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td><a>'.$aFiles[$i].'</a></td>';
   echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table></div>';
```

For the CSS:

```
.tbl_group {
  float: left;
}
```

With this approach, 2 tables are built side-by-side. `float: left` CSS will auto adjust the position of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not optimized, but this should more or less work:

```
$aFiles = array ("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N",);
$rows = 4;
$columns = floor((count($aFiles)/$rows))+1;

echo '<table>';
for ($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($j=0;$j<$columns;$j++) {
        echo '<td>';    
        if (isset($aFiles[$i+$j*$rows]))
            echo $aFiles[$i+$j*$rows];
        else 
            echo "&nbsp;";
        echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';    
}
echo '</table>';
```

You can change the number of rows if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Example bellow also works with associative array + arrays with odd elements.

#### Code for associative AND indexed array :

```
$aFiles = ['test'=>"A","B",'c'=>"C","D","E","F",'g'=>"G","H",'iii'=>"I"];
$aKeys = array_keys($aFiles);
$aRows = ceil(count($aFiles) / 2);

echo '<table>';
for($i=0; $i < $aRows; $i++) {
    echo 
        '<tr>' .
        '   <td>' . $aFiles[$aKeys[$i]] . '</td>' .
        '   <td>' . (isset($aKeys[$i+$aRows]) ? $aFiles[$aKeys[$i+$aRows]] : 'empty') . '</td>' .
        '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

#### Code for ONLY indexed array :

```
$aFiles = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"];
$aRows = ceil(count($aFiles) / 2);

echo "<table>";
for($i=0; $i < $aRows; $i++) {
    echo 
        "<tr>" .
        "   <td>" . $aFiles[$i] . "</td>" .
        "   <td>" . (isset($aFiles[$i+$aRows]) ? $aFiles[$i+$aRows] : "empty") . "</td>" .
        "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

#### Output for both examples is identical :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>I</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>empty</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one. Assume that your $aFiles contains a-z alphabetically.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($aFiles/2); $i++){
    echo '<tr><td><a>'.$aFiles[$i].'</a><td><td><a>'.$aFiles[$i+13].'</a><td></tr>'
}
```

Comment: you should not use the constant `13` in your calculations, replace with something derived from `count($aFiles)`.

Comment: `$aFiles[$i+13]` ? What do you want to achieve ?